# Не могу подключиться к базе данных python pymysql

Tags: python, база-данных, pymysql

разбираюсь в ООП и решил сделать класс подключения к базе данных с помощью библиотеки pymysql, и получается следующая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "connect_to_db.py", line 6, in <module>
class DBConnect(pymysql):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Вот сам код

```
import pymysql
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor
import socket

class DBConnect(pymysql): # наследуемся
    def __init__(self,host,user,password,db,charset,cursorclass):       
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.db = db
        self.charset = charet
        self.cursorclass = cursorclass
    def connect_to_DB():
        return pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',user = 'admin',password = '0000',db = 
        'test_db',charset = 'utf8mb4',cursorclass = DictCursor)             

 db = DBConnect(pymysql.cursors)
 db.connect_to_DB()


connection.close()
```

Comment: Во-первых, неверно наследуетесь, вернее зачем Вам наследоваться от модуля?. Во-вторых, в последней строке переменная connection не определена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pymysql
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor
import socket
class DBConnect:  # НЕ наследуемся
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, db, charset, cursorclass):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.db = db
        self.charset = charset
        self.cursorclass = cursorclass

    def connect_to_DB(self):
        return pymysql.connect(host=self.host, user=self.admin, password=self.password, db=self.db, charset=self.charset, cursorclass=self.cursorclass)


 db = DBConnect('localhost', 'admin', '0000', 'test_db', 'utf8mb4', DictCursor)
 connection = db.connect_to_DB()


connection.close()
```

Скорее всего тут еще ошибки есть, я не вникал в устройство pymysql.connect, вероятно неверно выбраны передаваемые атрибуты. Советую прочитать про то, как работает self - это можно сказать главная ошибка. Кроме того, наследование не применяется к модулям, только к классам.